# JsonSchemaGenerator Custom ContractResolver for strings

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

I want to create a schema from a custom object. The custom object have some string properties, these properties are schematized having the Type `String|Null`. How can i modify the `JSonSchemaGenerator` to convert strings to type `String` instead of `String|Null`?
In other words, if I serialize the Jsonschema I don'w want this:

```
{
  "title":"myObject",
  "type":"object",
  "properties":{
    "ID":{
      "required":true,
      "type":["string","null"]
    }
  }
}
```

but this:

```
{
  "title":"myObject",
  "type":"object",
  "properties":{
    "ID":{
      "required":true,
      "type":"string"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: All strings are nullable by default. Non-nullable strings don't exist in C#

Comment: Of course, but we are talking about json schema, not c#. in jsonSchema you are not forced to have this: `"Colour":{
"required":true,
"type":[
"string",
"null"
]
}`, You can have this `"Colour":{
"required":true,
"type":"string"
},`

Comment: have you solved this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
public string ID {get;set;}
```